# Editing index.html in apache2

Tags: apache2

I am very new to Ubuntu and Apache, and I have installed the latest Ubuntu onto an USB drive. By running `sudo get-apt install apache2` in Terminal I installed Apache.

I am trying to learn how to edit the `index.html` file, so far without success.

I would be very greatful for a step by step guide on how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

The file you're looking for is in `/var/www/html`, and it's owned by `root`, so you'll need to be `root` in order to able to edit it:

```
sudo -H gedit /var/www/html/index.html
```