# How do I remove Apache2's default index.html file?

Tags: apache2

So I have successfully installed joomla on my apache2 server, but the default page is still the index.html.  That is, when I click on the preview in my joomla manager, it goes to index.html!

The very same index.html recommends that I delete it, but for the life of me I can't figure out how.  I can't send it to trash, I can't manually delete it.  I can copy it to another folder and then delete the copy, but this doesn't really help.

From this quesiton: [Editing index.html in apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614472/editing-index-html-in-apache2)
It looks like with the right sudo command I could delete this file.  I would probably cd into the folder and run some sort of delete command?

Thanks in advance for the help!  If it weren't for this SE I don't know if I would be able to learn this new operating system!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest way is to run the following command from the command-line terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/www/html/index.html
```

The default location of that file is `/var/www/html/index.html`
The `rm` command is used to delete a file.
`sudo` is used to give the root permisions to delete this file, as there is a good chance your user is not a member of the correct group.

Comment: Just a side question, if I had cd'd into the folder, could I just have put sudo rm index.html?

Comment: Yes, that would of worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

This is because, during each deployment, CodeDeploy first deletes all files from the previous deployment, which are listed in a cleanup log file. If there are files in the target installation folders that aren’t listed in this cleanup file, the CodeDeploy agent by default interprets this as an error and fails the deployment.

Remove the files from the locations and instances to which they were previously deployed, and then try the deployment again.

Open your server on the terminal and type

**rm /var/www/html/index.html**

Redeploy again.